# Convertir respuesta API a fichero pdf

Tags: php, api, pdf, conversión-de-tipos

Estoy trabajando con una API de un tercero en PHP y tengo un problema, es que la API me devuelve un string que es el contenido de un pdf, empieza por %PDF-1.4 %���� %PDF-1.4 %���� %PDF-1.4 %���� 3 0 obj <> /Contents 4 0 R>> endobj 4 0 obj <> stream x�, el problema que tengo es que no se como convertirlo a fichero PDF para que me lo descargue.

He utilizado fwrite pero siempre me dice que el fichero es corrupto.

Me podéis ayudar?

GRACIAS POR ADELANTADO

Comment: también he probado con base64 pero hago algo mal porque siempre me da el archivo como corrupto. GRACIAS

Answer (score 1):

Por fin, evidentemente si no pongo cabecera pdf no funcionará...

```
//guardo respuesta api en variable %$pdf
$pdf = descargas();
//Añado cabecera PDF
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
//Escritura de datos en fichero factura1.pdf
file_put_contents('factura1.pdf',descargas());
echo 'Done';
```